# GAE Queue Statistics numbers wrong on development console

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm seeing very strange behavior in some code that checks the QueueStatistics for a queue to see if any tasks are currently running.  To the best of my knowledge there are NO tasks running, and none have been queued up for the past 12+ hours.   The development console corroborates this, saying that there are 0 tasks in the queue.

Looking at the QueueStatistics information in my debugger though, confirms that my process is exiting because it's seeing on the order of 500+ (!!!) tasks in the queue.  It also says it ran >1000 tasks in the past minute, yet it ran 0 tasks in the past hour.  If I parse through the ETA Usec, the time is "accurately" showing as if the ETA is within the next minute of when the QueueStatistics were pulled.

This is happening repeatedly whenever I re-run my servlet, and the first thing the servlet does is check the queue statistics.  No other servlets, tasks, or cron jobs are running as this is my local development server.  Yet the queue statistics continue to insist I've got hundreds of tasks running.

I couldn't find any other reports of this behavior, but it feels like I must be missing something major here in regards to Queue Statistics.  The code I'm using is very simple:

```
Queue taskQueue = QueueFactory.getQueue("myQueue");
QueueStatistics stats = taskQueue.fetchStatistics();
if (stats.getNumTasks() > 0) { return; }
```

What am I missing?  Are queue statistics entirely unreliable on the local dev server?

Answer (score 0):

If it works as expected when deployed then that's the standard to go by.

Lots of things don't work as they do in the deployed environment (parallel threads are not parallel, backend support is somewhat broken for addressing them at the time of writing) so deploy deploy deploy!

Another example is the channel API. When used locally it uses polling, you'll see 100's of those if you look in the logs/browser debug. But when deployed all is well and it works as expected.

Comment: While not a vote of confidence, thanks for the suggestion.  I've also noticed this myself and it's becoming my go-to answer when things are wonky.  It's tough on things like this where I need to use the debugger, but can't because the local dev server functions differently.

Comment: I've found logging.debug("in function x") etc invaluable for live "debugging".